# React Controlled Components not receiving inputs properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't figure out Controlled Components. Doing everything almost exactly as in the example in the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components .

What happens is only one input character gets into the input. Upon the next character entry, the previous one gets replaced. When I enter 'asdf', I get this:

```
changeName a
changeName s
changeName d
changeName f
```

Here's my code:

```
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this)
    this.handleChangeDescription = this.handleChangeDescription.bind(this)
    this.state = ({name:'',description:''})
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
    return false
  }

  handleChangeName(event) {
    console.log('changeName',event.target.value)
    this.setState({name: event.target.value.substr(0, 8)});
  }

  handleChangeDescription(event) {
    this.setState({description: event.target.value.substr(0, 140)});
  }

  render () {
    return (
    <Row>
      <Col xs={12} lg={12} className="beacon-fields">
        <Input id="name" help="Name" className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChangeName} />
        <Input id="description" help="Description" className="form-control" type="text" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.handleChangeDescription} />
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a JSBin or JSFiddle, i tried but failed: http://jsbin.com/vezedegoji/edit?js,output

Comment: You got me on the right track, updated the question. In actual code, I have the shouldComponentUpdate function that does useful stuff. But here's a way to reproduce the situation. http://jsbin.com/mepelajowo/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: If you're returning false from `shouldComponentUpdate` you'll never see any updates. I think that within your `shouldComponentUpdate` is your problem.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was rather obvious. `shouldComponentUpdate` method prevented the render from executing, which means the inputs was not appearing in the input fields. The solution was rather simple:

```
shouldComponentUpdate (nextProps, nextState) {
  if (this.state !== nextState) {
    return true
  }    
  return false
}
```